Show that an integral is positive
Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ be an integrable and increasing function with $f(0)=0$ and $1 < f(1) < \infty$. Under what conditions on $f$ is the following inequality true for integer $n\geq 1$?
$$\int_0^1 [f(x)^{n-1} - f(x)^{n}]dx \geq 0$$
Attempt It is easy to prove $n=1$ (i.e., the lower bound is poitive), but beyond that I could not succeed.

A sufficient, but not necessarily minimal, condition for $f(x)$ that guarantees the inequality, is that $f(x) \leq 1 \forall x \in [0,1]$. This ensures that $1 - f(x) \geq 0$, making the integrand non-negative, and thus the integral is guaranteed to be so $\forall n \geq 1$.
However, if $f(x) > 1$ for some $ x \in [0,1]$, we would need more information about the behaviour of $f(x)$ to determine if the integral is non-negative. Not sure what information, as it would depend on $f$ but it would probably be to do with things like the derivatives, etc

Edit: Just to clarify why I'm talking about $1-f(x)$ in the first place is just due to the fact that the integral becomes:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)^{n-1} \left( 1 - f(x) \right) dx.
$$
